# How to set MQGetOptions if I do not want any conversion

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-mq

I am using IBM Websphere MQ v6 and I am connecting to it using a Java EE program. 
I want to know how to set the MQ Get Options so that no conversion is done.

Can I use the field MQFMT_NONE for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported.  Depending on the client and QMgr versions, WMQ messages may carry properties and JMS header data in the RFH2 message header.  Because this header is part of the message payload and not part of the MQMD or other message metadata, WMQ JMS classes will *always* use `MQGMO_CONVERT` when retrieving messages to insure that it can read the RFH2 headers.  If WMQ did not do this then the message properties and other metadata in the RFH2 header would often not be readable by the client app's JMS classes.

For more on this topic, please see the Infocenter's [Message Conversion](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm25522_.htm) section in the Using Java manual.  Also, please see the Technote [MQGMO_CONVERT switching functionality for Java Message Service applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642646/how-to-set-mqgetoptions-if-i-do-not-want-any-conversion) for some behavior differences across versions.

Comment: So if I do not want any conversion, I do not set MQGMO_CONVERT to MQgetOptions right? By Default, the get command does not convert?

Comment: The post says you are using JEE which, as noted above, does not expose the `MQGMO`.  The JMS classes *must* convert in order to read their own metadata.  However if you are using the pure Java classes, these use the native WMQ API and the `MQGMO_CONVERT` is exposed and can be set.  By default *with the native API* conversion is NOT performed unless requested.